# creating a new list for each index from the array

Tags: javascript, html

My solution: 
https://jsfiddle.net/c96hv9tj/1/

```
function filler(list, arr){
    let b = document.createElement("li");

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        b.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));
    } 
    list.appendChild(b);
}
```

I'm trying to make it create a new li for each index from the array
help please.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put everything **inside** the loop like this :

```js
function filler(list, arr) {

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let b = document.createElement("li");
    b.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i]));
    list.appendChild(b);
  }

}


let ul = document.getElementById("fillthislist");
let entries = ["Shmi", "Anakin", "Luke"];

filler(ul, entries);
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Fill an empty list with the contents of an array</h1>
  <ul id=fillthislist>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

For better performance don't appendChild to the document element. Use a [Document Fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) instead.

```
function filler(list, listItems) {

  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  listItems.forEach(item => {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
    fragment.appendChild(li);
  });

  list.appendChild(fragment);
}
```

> Since the document fragment is in memory and not part of the main DOM
>   tree, appending children to it does not cause page reflow (computation
>   of element's position and geometry). Consequently, using document
>   fragments often results in better performance.

---

JsFiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/c96hv9tj/11/